# VSTS - Create Process Parameters in Release Defintion

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In Visual Studion Teams Services Build Definitions I can outsource Task Settings 
to Process Parameters by clicking on the (i) icon and then on "Link".

[image: Screenshot]

I really like this feature and I would like to do the same in a Release Definition. But I cannot find a way to create Process Parameters in a Release Definition (no "Link" option). If I select one of the Release Defintion Templates (e.g. Azure App Service Deployment) there are a few OOTB Process Parameters which I can use, but I cannot create new parameters. I cannot use variables as they only store string values and for some release tasks, specific settings (e.g. Azure Subscription) cannot use a variable but a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

While this isn't supported in the GUI yet, you should be able to do accomplish this on the underlying json you can export from VSTS.  This json has a processParameters collection for each environment, and a dataSourceBindings.  Here is a screenshot showing how to do an Azure Subscription.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So I would have to export my release definition and import it as a new definition, right? This doesn't feel good, because I would loose the complete release history, service hooks and so on if I wanted to add a parameter. Hope the feature will be supported in the GUI soon.

Answer (score 0):

The Process parameters feature is only available in build editor. [What are process parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/archive/preview/2017-user-experience#parameters)?

Regarding some settings of some release tasks (e.g. Azure Subscription), you can’t use variable, but you can custom build/release task to support it. ([Add a Build task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/add-build-task))

On the other hand, you can’t create/add new parameters to release task dynamically, just can specify the parameters in arguments input box.